# how to get last weeek dates from today to last 7 days date

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures

i have a table with column:

```
Registereddate          orgid

2010-06-05 10:16:00     1
2010-06-05 10:10:00     2
2010-06-04 22:31:00     3
...                     .
.                       .....
.
.
.
```

i need to get only last weeek dates and orgid from today to last 7 days date..

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select Registereddate, orgid
from your_table
where Registereddate > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
and DATEPART(week, Registereddate) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())
```

This query will return all records having a registered date later than 7 days before current date/time.

If you don't want the hours to be taken into account, then try something like this (works only on 2008 due to date datatype cast):

```
select Registereddate, orgid
from your_table
where Registereddate > DATEADD(day, -7, cast(GETDATE() as date))
and DATEPART(week, Registereddate) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())
```

Here's the version without the hours for 2005:

```
    select Registereddate, orgid
    from your_table
    where Registereddate > DATEADD(day, -7, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 
101)))

and DATEPART(week, Registereddate) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())
```

Comment: thanks for yr reply . but this gives me entire date before 7 days. if no registration done on last week two days it takes previous week two days. but i need oly last week dates.not before last week ones.

Comment: Ow, I see, so you don't want a full week to be returned, except on the last day of the week, is that what you mean?

Comment: I've updated the queries so that only records from the current week are returned.